# How to prove this function is L-continuous almost-everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Definition:** Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ a measure space. Some property P (in this case, the continuity) is said to be satisfied `almost everywhere` in X if there exists a set $N \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$ and for all $x \in X\setminus N$, the property P holds.

**Problem**: Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ functions and g continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ with $g\neq0$. The function defined

$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      g(x) & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \\
      0 & x \in \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}
$$
prove that $f$ is $\mathcal{L}_{a.e}$ continuous (that is, f is continuous almost-everywhere using the Lebesgue measure).

Is there an easy way to prove this?

Comment: The definition of "$\mathcal{L}_{a,e}$ continuous" is unclear.  What precisely does "for all $x\in X\setminus N$, the property $P$ holds" means when $P$ is continuity?  (There are at least two reasonable interpretations, and one of them makes the statement you are trying to prove false.)

Comment: @EricWofsey It means that there exists a set "N" where its Lebesgue measure is 0 and in the complement of N (in this case with respect to $R$) the function f is continuous. Therefore, f is continuous almost everywhere except in this "N". For example, the function f(x) = 0 if x < 0 and f(x) = 1 if x $\geq$ 0, is continuous almost everywhere because there exists N = {0} such that L(N) = 0 and f is continuous in $R\setminus \{0\} $.

Comment: Ah, but what does "continuous in the complement of $N$" mean? It could mean either continuous at each point of the complement of $N$, or that the function is continuous when restricted to the complement of $N$.  Those aren't the same thing!

Comment: @EricWofsey the first thing you said! f is continuous for every $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus N$

Comment: In that case the statement you are trying to prove is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E=\mathbb Q$ then  $E$ has measure $0$ and the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb R \setminus E$ is $g$ which is continuous.

You cannot prove the existence of a set $E$ of measure $0$ such that $f$ is continuous at each point of $\mathbb R \setminus E$. For example, if $g(x)=1+|x|$ then the corresponding $f$ is not continuous at any point!. If your null set exists then we get the conclusion that the real line has measure $0$!.